# USB Headphones Recognized but not Working on Ubuntu

Tags: sound, headphones

USB headphones are recognized in sound settings but not working on Ubuntu. What do I do?

Comment: Please add more details to this question. Which Ubuntu version, which type of headphones, check if your volume is muted, sound card. Give us something we can work with.

Comment: It's a self-answer question and I wrote the most Google-able question for future readers.

Comment: No problem then. Let me retract my close vote also a +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In terminal type**

```
alsamixer
```

Then hit <kbd>F6</kbd> to open the menu we will use.

You may see three sections, Auto Gain Control, Headset, and Headset 1. In my case Headset 1 was muted and had no volume (red/white) in the bar. Both Headset and Headset 1 need to be unmuted and have some volume in the bar for your headphones to work.

Use the left and right arrow keys to scroll between sections. **Pressing the <kbd>M</kbd> key unmutes**. **MM means muted while 00 means unmuted**. Ensure both Headset and Headset 1 are unmuted (00). In my case, Headset 1 was muted.

Now **use the up and down arrow keys to put volume in both bars**. In my case, the volume buttons on my keyboard successfully controlled the Headset section but did nothing for the Headset 1 section which had volume all the way down. Press the up key on Headset 1 to put some volume in that bar.

If both bars are unmuted and have volume in them then your headphones should work if this was the issue. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit, changes will be saved automatically.