# Headphones not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, sound, 22.04, alsa, thinkpad

Laptop: ThinkPad E495
Dual Boot With Windows 10
Ubuntu 22.04

Whenever I change OS from windows to Ubuntu, the headphone does not work properly. The sound keeps coming from both earphones + system sounds of the laptop. Headphones are not recognized anywhere.

I have followed [Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working/147603#147603) this method by lexical lemon, but it only worked the first time. I have edited my *alsa-base.conf* file but it does not work anymore.

I have followed Sammy's answer from [USB Headphones Recognized but not Working on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252324/usb-headphones-recognized-but-not-working-on-ubuntu) but alsamixer doesn't recognize my headphone at all.

My headphone is JBL C50HI. I have checked hardware with phones and other devices. Everything is OK, except Ubuntu 22.04 is neither auto-recognizing, nor manually working.

Alsamixer:

[image: Alsamixer image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Since it was a dual boot, I have finally solved it by unplugging the headphones whenever I shift from one OS to another. So first I unplug the headphones, and then change the OS, and re-plug the headphones again. This has apparently solved my issue with sound output coming only from the headphones and not the laptop speakers. I don't know if it's an update/driver issue.

Hope it helps anyone else who is facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install pavucontrol

This is for the volume control. And website if you need more.
https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed answer? the documentation in the site you provided - 'does not have much to say'